# Does the send and receive function calls in MPI involve IO on the system necessarily and always?

Tags: networking, parallel-processing, operating-system, mpi, distributed-computing

I know this would be a difficult question to answer as the exact behaviour of MPI routines is somewhat environment dependent.

I am convinced that if the communicating processes are placed on two different machines which have no hardware to connect except the typical Ethernet network, then IO calls are must as it will translate to a remote call which involves all of networking-stack.

But, what about the cases where the communicating processes are running on same machine as in they have their address space on the same memory hardware (RAM) ? How much of the networking stack be used and will this kind of call be significantly faster in execution than the other one?

Comment: MPI implementations generally use different approaches for intra-node communication (e.g. the hardware interconnect) and intra-node communication (e.g. shared memory), so it is unlikely intra node communications will ever use the network stack. FWIW, Open MPI would use `btl/tcp` for inter-node communications (over TCP/IP) and `btl/vader` for intra-node communications.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet  So OpenMPI uses shared memory architecture (which one owuld call `bll/vader`)  for high performance intra-node communication,  https://www.open-mpi.org/faq/?category=sm

Thank you so much for showing the correct keyword to look for.